# batch script: string.format (or applicable function) to inject one string into another

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, string-formatting

File A:

```
{
"key": "{0}"
}
```

File B:

```
"value from file B"
```

I am trying to write a cmd.exe script that will format file B into file A, and generate a new file C as output

Output File C:

```
File A: 
{
"key": "value from file B"
}
```

In C# I could to this by just loading the two files into string variables, then calling:

```
string file_c = String.Format(file_a, file_b);
```

How can I do the equivalent in cmd.exe script (or ps1 script if the functionality is not in cmd.exe - I would prefer command script)

Comment: Have you checked the -f command? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2008.06.windowspowershell.aspx

Comment: You couldn't do that in C#, it would throw `System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.` because of the unescaped `{` in the JSON style hash opening line ([test code on repl.it](https://repl.it/OD3n/0)). If you fix that in the file then you could do the same thing in PowerShell, since it's a .Net language and can use the same string and formatting mechanism  `$c = (get-content a.txt -raw) -f (get-content b.txt -raw)` .

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, this would look something like:

```
Get-Content FileA.txt | ForEach-Object {
  if ( $_ -match '{\d+}' ) {
    $_ -f ((Get-Content FileB.txt) -replace '^"','' -replace '"$','')
  }
  else {
    $_
  }
}
```

I'm assuming you don't want the embedded quotes from `FileB.txt` (hence the `-replace` operators).